# The origin of the kanji 買

Tags: kanji

The kanji 買　（buy) contains the kanji 貝　（shellfish).

Is it because the origin of the kanji  買 lies in the process of buying shellfish?

Does anyone know the story behind the kanji 買?

Thank you!

Comment: Highly relevant: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/36969/the-radical-%e8%b2%9d-and-its-relation-to-economic-characters-such-as-%e8%b2%a8-%e8%b3%87-etc

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
[甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
[image]
[佚](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)462
[合集11436](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=11436&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>商
[金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
[image]
買車卣
[集成4874](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=4874&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty)
[簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
[image]
秦律十八86
[睡虎地秦簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts)</kbd><kbd>今
[楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
[image]</kbd>

「買{ばい}」([Baxter-Sagart OC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Baxter%E2%80%93Sagart_(2014)): **/*mˤrajʔ/**, *to buy*) is composed of semantic「貝」(*cowrie shell*, used as currency in Ancient China, indicating *money*) and phonetic「网{ぼう}」(**/*maŋʔ/**).

> 「网」depicts a *net*, and this word is written as「網」in Modern Japanese.